# gMail delegate e-mail with a single button click

Tags: gmail

I use G-Suite with gmail for my e-mail. I'd like to have a single button at the top of the mail page (like the archive and delete buttons) with which I can forward the e-mail without any further confirmation or other UX to my assistant and simultaneously archive it.

Is there a way to achieve that, and if so, how?

Comment: There is no built-in way for that. If you are looking for a software recommendation try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Is there also no plugin or scripting system that could allow to add this feature?

Comment: Perhaps Tampermoney/Greasemonkey, maybe other web browser extensions. You could use Google Apps Script to create a Gmail add-on (but not to add "a single button at the topo of the email page"). If you will build your own user defined function / bookmarklet / web browser extension you might need  Gmail API.

Comment: Related [How to inject code into Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142101/88163)